# How to handle Postgres HStore type with Rust Cornucopia

Tags: postgresql, rust, codegen, cornucopia

When using [Cornucopia](https://cornucopia-rs.netlify.app/book/introduction/introduction) to generate Rust structs from a managed Postgres database I get the following error:

> this query contains an unsupported type (name: identities, type: hstore)

We have a few rows like this in our database and it would be great to not have to return everything as `json` and manually parse since that would defeat the purpose of auto-generating types in the first place.

Here is and example SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

and here is the generation command:

```bash
cornucopia --serialize live $DATABASE_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue for the time being by casting to json in the SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    registered_at::varchar,
    created_at::varchar,
    COALESCE(hstore_to_json(identities), '{}'::json) AS identities,
    email, 
    id 
FROM users;
```

it's a bit more verbose, but at least it's working!